# org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage

Tags: java, jsf, activemq-classic

i have jsf applications
I had tried get message from ActiveMQ from other app,

this is fragments from my code

```
@ResourceAdapter("activemq")
public class Listener implements MessageListener {

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    String msg = null;
    try {
        msg =(((ActiveMQObjectMessage) message).getObject()).toString();//here is error!!!!
        System.out.println("====================");
        System.out.println(msg);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

why here `(ActiveMQObjectMessage) message)` i will get error

org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage

in debagger i can see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbwoi.png), and i jast want String "update1"
my dependencies

```
<dependencies>

    <!--For Servlet Container like Tomcat-->
    <!--http://download.java.net/maven/2-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-b03</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-b03</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--&lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/javax.ejb-api &ndash;&gt;-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-ejb3</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Comment: Are you publishing your object as a same ActiveMQObjectMessage ?

Comment: Yes. pom from 1th app         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
            <version>5.14.5</version>
        </dependency>                                                                           from 2nd                                                                                     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.14.5</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Can you describe the code how you are publishing your message to Broker.

Comment: #Component
public class MessageSender {
 #Autowired
 JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

 public void sendMessage(final String msg) {

  jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator(){
    @Override
    public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException{
     ObjectMessage objectMessage = session.createObjectMessage(msg);
     return objectMessage;
    }
   });
 }
}

Comment: i cannot write in code format, ctrl + k and 4 spase not working, sorry.

Comment: Make sure that the object which you are publishing ( ObjectMessage in your case) should be the same which will be consumed in OnMessage method of consumer ( ActiveMQObjectMessage in your case). Re check the package structure or i think you should publish the object as ActiveMQObjectMessage as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should check, if you have duplicate classes defined with this maven plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-ban-duplicate-classes</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <banDuplicateClasses>
              <findAllDuplicates>true</findAllDuplicates>
            </banDuplicateClasses>
          </rules>
          <fail>true</fail>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Before you downvote please read my disclaimer ;-) This is not a proved answer. But it's not possible to write it as a comment due to length restrictions.